# How to communicate with Shiny and TclTk widget in R

Tags: r, widget, shiny, parameter-passing, tk-toolkit

I am writing a program in Shiny, but I want to use TclTk for the beginning because it looks cleaner. I want to pass data that is gathered in TclTk to Shiny. I think I can do this by writing a CSV file and then doing it, but is there a better way? Also, how could I start my Shiny app right out of TclTk and make it find the data that was gathered from TclTk? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yes, you can do it with a CSV. Shiny and TclTk cannot be easily combined - you need some form of interprocess communication.

Comment: Starting a shiny app from a tcltk windows should be just a button click away, but if you start shiny in the "button click event handler" the tcltk window will freeze I guess. Did you succeed? Please report to let us learn from your experiences!

Comment: Do you want to keep the TclTk window open while using shiny? Do you even want to enter other data in the TclTk window and update the shiny app? This would make think much more complicated than just closing the TclTk window and launching shiny while using the variables from the same workspace.